# Change framework paths in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I want to add Facebook login button to an Xcode Project and it tells me that I should add it's folder's directory to FrameWork paths.

How can I do this in Xcode?

I clicked on `Debug` and added the directory to second parenthesis, but it tells me that the framework is not found